# Graph API authorization denied

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I'm currently writing a Blazor App. I built it off the MS Visual Studios Template and included Graph Client via the checkbox. In the App Registration I have granted the AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All Delegated Permission and have it consented and on my user token I can see that permission in the scope however when I call a delete on

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/OBJECTID/appRoleAssignedTo/APPROLEASSIGNEMNTID

I get an unauthorized error. The Graph API Docs say all that is needed to call a delete on this API with a delegated account is the AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All permission It is fully consented, and I can't figure out for the life of me why these doesn't work.

If I log into the Application with a Global Admin account and perform the action, it works fine but not as a normal user that will be using the application. The Application has its own function that can add/remove users to its App Users/Groups assignments and select their role but I can't get a delete, or post request to work when I have the correct permission on my access token

does anyone have a clue why the delegated permissions still do not work? I even manually defined the scope in the code itself to include this permission with no luck.

When I decode my token through [https://jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/)

I have these scopes:
"scp": "Application.ReadWrite.All AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All Contacts.Read Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Group.Read.All GroupMember.Read.All openid People.Read People.Read.All profile User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All email"

Which should be more than enough to call delete on appRoleAssignedTo API Endpoint

I've removed and re-added the permissions and delegated access with admin consent.
I've decoded the token to confirm the access scope is on the token.

This is just testing out a rewrite of an older web forms app the same permission is used in the Web format but it's application based instead of delegated and it works there but with this being a blazer web assembly I can't do application based permissions it has to be delegated.

If I log into the application with a global administrator account works fine. But is the normal user it doesn't work.